# How to print an array in Python by the last digit descendingly?

Tags: python

How can I print a list by their last digit descendingly. For an example if I have the following list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 36, 82]
```

It needs to be sorted like:

```
[36, 55, 44, 3, 82, 2, 1]
```

So basically, the last digit has higher priority in the list, and if two numbers have the same last digit, than the higher value goes first.

Comment: Can give a more verbose explanation what do you want. I don't understand your sorting conditions at all.

Answer (score 8):

Just use a custom key function and reverse the results — it's all in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 44, 55, 36, 82]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x % 10, x // 10), reverse=True)
[36, 55, 44, 3, 82, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the lambda x: (x % 10, x) works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: str(x)[::-1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, fails for example for `l = [312, 22]` which it turns into `[22, 312]`.